# Hadoop Cluster Architecture

Tags: hadoop

I’m trying to define the architecture of an Hadoop cluster (about 10/15 nodes), mainly used for batch treatment (indicators pre-aggregation).

I identified 5 roles for my nodes: Master, Master HA, Slave, Service, Gateway and tried to distinguish the software component to install on them.
Here is the result. I'm not sure about it. Do the clients (Hive/Sqoop/Spark) have to be installed on the slave nodes?

[image]
Is this architecture look relevant to you? Is something missing? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
Do the clients (Hive/Sqoop/Spark) have to be installed on the slave nodes?
```

Not really. Clients are nodes / servers which have the libraries to run your Hive/Sqoop/Spark jobs. As long as you submit you jobs from that machine there should be no problem.
According to me the architecture looks okay.